# ORA-20987: APEX Column EPI not found in table EMPLOYEE

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex-5.1

In my oracle APEX form I added new empty columns and now when I try to open my form from the application using edit to fill the new form fields I'm getting this error. when i check in debug error i see

ORA-20987: APEX Column EPI not found in table EMPLOYEE

```
Contact your application administrator.

Technical Info (only visible for developers)

is_internal_error: true
apex_error_code: WWV_FLOW_DML.COLUMN_NOT_FOUND
component.type: APEX_APPLICATION_PAGE_PROCESS
component.id: 8364816106618504
component.name: Fetch Row from EMPLOYEE
error_backtrace:
----- PL/SQL Call Stack -----
  object      line  object
  handle    number  name
0xef640df0       935  package body APEX_050100.WWV_FLOW_ERROR
0xef640df0      1003  package body APEX_050100.WWV_FLOW_ERROR
0xef640df0      1395  package body APEX_050100.WWV_FLOW_ERROR
0xec11d1e8       435  package body APEX_050100.WWV_FLOW_DML
0xec11d1e8       688  package body APEX_050100.WWV_FLOW_DML
0xe39dfb08       538  package body APEX_050100.WWV_FLOW_PROCESS_NATIVE
0xe39dfb08      1137  package body APEX_050100.WWV_FLOW_PROCESS_NATIVE
0xeccd8f20      2397  package body APEX_050100.WWV_FLOW_PLUGIN
0xecfc4888       191  package body APEX_050100.WWV_FLOW_PROCESS
0xecfc4888       434  package body APEX_050100.WWV_FLOW_PROCESS
0xef162b50      2582  package body APEX_050100.WWV_FLOW_PAGE
0xf1b0a070      4922  package body APEX_050100.WWV_FLOW
0xecc32648       173  procedure APEX_050100.F
0xec759040         2  anonymous block
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue Resolved. I did not mention the table name correctly.